# Error when create new payment method in Odoo 15

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I want to create new method payment but it gives me this error in Odoo V15.

> ` File
> "/cityvape/cityvape-server/addons/account/models/account_payment_method.py",
> line 28, in create
> if information.get('mode') == 'multi': Exception
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/cityvape/cityvape-server/odoo/http.py", line 643, in
> _handle_exception
> return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/cityvape/cityvape-server/odoo/http.py", line 301, in
> _handle_exception
> raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

This is the code

```
@api.model_create_multi
    def create(self, vals_list):
        payment_methods = super().create(vals_list)
        methods_info = self._get_payment_method_information()
        for method in payment_methods:
            information = methods_info.get(method.code)

            if information.get('mode') == 'multi':
                method_domain = method._get_payment_method_domain()

                journals = self.env['account.journal'].search(method_domain)

                self.env['account.payment.method.line'].create([{
                    'name': method.name,
                    'payment_method_id': method.id,
                    'journal_id': journal.id
                } for journal in journals])
        return payment_methods
```

I installed third party module but it gave me same error.

Comment: Please format your code block(s), logs and errors, in order to make your question more readable, and receive better quality answers. For more information, take a look on this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

`information = methods_info.get(method.code)` this line has error... It is returning `None Value` because it seems either `methods_info.get(method.code)` is returning an empty dictionary or `information.get('mode')` sometimes returns an empty dictionary.

Use `Logger info` to trace the value of both or use `print function` to print the value in terminal to check whether the correct value is passed or not

Comment: Please can you tell me how to do it im don't know how to do it

Comment: use print statement below this line `information = methods_info.get(method.code)`

type: `print('###############',information )`
and check the result in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in Odoo 16 and I solved it extending `_get_payment_method_information()` and adding the codes.

First I created the payment methods in an XML datafile:

```
<data noupdate="0">
    <record id="account_payment_method_check_out" model="account.payment.method">
        <field name="name">Check</field>
        <field name="code">check</field>
        <field name="payment_type">outbound</field>
    </record>

    <record id="account_payment_method_transfer_in" model="account.payment.method">
        <field name="name">Transfer</field>
        <field name="code">transfer</field>
        <field name="payment_type">inbound</field>
    </record>
    <record id="account_payment_method_transfer_out" model="account.payment.method">
        <field name="name">Transfer</field>
        <field name="code">transfer</field>
        <field name="payment_type">outbound</field>
    </record>
</data>
```

Then I added the codes to `_get_payment_method_information()`:

```
class AccountPaymentMethod(models.Model):
_inherit = 'account.payment.method'

    @api.model
    def _get_payment_method_information(self):
        res = super()._get_payment_method_information()
        res['transfer'] = {'mode': 'multi', 'domain': [('type', '=', 'bank')]}
        res['check'] = {'mode': 'multi', 'domain': [('type', '=', 'bank')]}
        return res
```